# How do I download image from firebase storage folder with python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download image from firebase storage which the resouce folder

[image: 1]

can anyone teach me how to do?

my english is not good forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you download any image in Firebase, you will find in your local folder as "img.png"

The credentials.json should be in the same folder you run this code in and you can retrieve it from Firebase, its particular to your account

In my case my storage bucket is called 'aisparkdev-tinder.appspot.com'

When generating the blob variable, the string is just the path to your image.

```
import urllib
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage
cred = credentials.Certificate("credentials.json")

    # Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
appF = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, 
                                    {'storageBucket': 'aisparkdev-tinder.appspot.com',}, 
                                    name='storage')

bucket = storage.bucket(app=appF)

blob = bucket.blob("profileImages/"+profilePic+".jpg")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300), method='GET'), ".\\img.png")
```

Comment: it'works on first time ,but when I run secound time it show the error :                           
ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.

Comment: and i want to get all image in folder but i don't know the filles name what shold i do

Comment: So if you need to retrieve from different apps, you can create different 'appF' and name them 'appSomething', but you should also modify the [name='storage'] to something different too, since that creates a new variable called storage in runtime

Comment: To find files in a folder in firebase you could use
storage = firebase.storage()
files = storage.list_files()
for file in files:
    print(storage.child(file.name).get_url(None))

Comment: when I use storage = firebase.storage() files = storage.list_files() I can get all file in storage, but I just want to get the one folder named uploads and download from uploads  ,not all file in storage

Comment: and the ValueError: problem is solved thanks